# Nozzle - Modelica

Tags: modelica

I want to model and simulate a hydraulic system in Modelica. In this system I have a nozzle. I want to include the nozzle in Modelica. But I cant find a suitable component in Modelica which represents the nozzle. Do you have an idea if there is a nozzle component in Modelica library ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the package `Modelica.Fluid.Valves`. In particular, the model `Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveVaporizing` could be what you are looking for.